# Another hard level of the game „Flow Mania”

Tags: grid-deduction

[image: Flow Mania, level 123]

Can you, please, help me to solve this level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The puzzle can be solved like this:

> You can easily see that blue must go round the top three yellowish
>  points, otherwise lemon can't be linked. Blue could go round pink and
>  red too, but that route would prevent green or white from linking.
>  So there is only one route for blue, and the rest follows easily.
>  
>  [image]

Coverage 100%.